# Filling in QPainter drawn lines/shapes

Tags: qt, bitmap, qpainter

I need to fill in/shade in the negative/positive side of waves in Qt.

I believe I am going to use `painter.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)` to draw wave lines on a pixmap/bitmap. The negative or positive crests of the wave have to be filled in though based on a user toggle.

Any ideas as to how this could be done? Is there some way to tell the painter you're drawing a shape?

An idea I had was to draw each crest of the wave as if it were a shape (the line down the middle encloses the area) and then it could easily be filled in. But I can't seem to find a way to tell the painter class that I'm making a custom shape. Below is a visual representation of what needs to be displayed

[image: Waves drawn on a bitmap].

Comment: See [`QPainterPath`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html) and [`QPainterPathStroker`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpathstroker.html).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: If I could mark this as solved now I would, thanks @G.M.

Comment: If you think it's solved you may either write an answer by yourself or delete the question. As this was a trivial question (hint for the appropriate Qt doc. was sufficient) I would tend to the latter. In this case, @Micho will probably lose 2 rep. points for editing. I hope he can live with this. (As I "ref-ed" him, he will notice and might intervene if he does not agree.)